# Native geolocation ionic watch position working on background but not when phone is locked

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, native, background-mode

I'm using this code:

```
this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((localizacion) => {
  console.log("En el enviarPos", localizacion);
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
}, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

It works in background, but only doesn't work when the phone is locked.

Error:

```
GeolocationPositionError {code: 3, message: "Timeout expired"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing same issue but I switched to [Geocoder](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/native-geocoder/), and it's working fine for me, also it gives lot of info,

=> For Ionic 3

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder

npm install --save @ionic-native/native-geocoder@4
```

=> For Ionic 4

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder

npm install --save @ionic-native/native-geocoder
```